# Concept for temporary data in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a question regarding the usage of Cassandra for temporary data (Data which is written once to the database, which is read once from the database and then deleted).

We are using Cassandra, to exchange data between processes which are running on different machines / different containers. Process1 is writing some data to the Cassandra, Process2 is reading this data. After that, data can be deleted.
As we learned that Cassandra doesn't like writing and deleting data very often in one table because of tombestones and performance issues, we are creating temporary tables for this.

Process1 : Create table, write data to table.
Process2 : Read data from table, drop table.

But doing this in a very high number (500-1000 tables create and drop per hour) we are facing problems on our schema synchronization between our nodes (we have cluster with 6 nodes).
The Cassandra cluster got very slow, we got a lot of timeout warnings, we got errors about different schemas on the nodes, the CPU load on the cluster nodes grew up to 100% and then the cluster was dead :-).

Is Cassandra the right database for this usecase ?

Is it a problem of how we configured our cluster ?

Will it be a better solution to create temporary keyspaces for this ?

Has anyone experience of how to handle such usecase with Cassandra ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any database here. Your use case is to enable your applications to handshake with each other to share data asynchronously. There are two possible solutions:

1) For Batch based writes and reads consider using something like HDFS for intermediate storage. Process 1 writes data files in HDFS directories and Process 2 reads it from HDFS.

2) For message based system consider something like Kafka. Process 1 process the data stream and writes into Kafka Topics and Process 2 consumers reads data from Kafka Topics. Kafka do provides Ack/Nack features.

Continuously creating and deleting number of tables in Cassandra is not a good practice and is never recommended.